# NSURL add parameters to fileURLWithPath method

Tags: iphone, ios, parameters, append, nsurl

I use this line of code to load a local html file into a web view:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html"]];
```

However I want to add some http parameters to the url with no luck so far.

I've tried this:

```
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"?param1=1"];
```

But after this a html doesn't load in webview.

Is there a way to load local html file in webview with params ?

Comment: If you `NSlog` the URL after you added the parameters are they included ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html"]];

NSString *URLString = [url absoluteString];   
NSString *queryString = @"?param1=1"; 
NSString *URLwithQueryString = [URLString stringByAppendingString: queryString];  

NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLwithQueryString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)10.0 ];

[web loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: This doesn't always work. If the URL ends with fragments (i.e. #something) then it becomes an invalid URL after running this piece of code.

Answer (score 6):

The most upvoted answer by **Prince** doesn't always work.

In iOS 7 Apple introduced `NSURLComponents` class, we can leverage that to securely add a query into `NSURL`.

```
NSURL *contentURL = ...;
NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL:contentURL resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
NSMutableArray *queryItems = [components.queryItems mutableCopy];
if (!queryItems) queryItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[queryItems addObject:[NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"access_token" value:@"token_here"]];
components.queryItems = queryItems;
NSURL *newURL = components.URL;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: One note here: queryItems property of NSURLComponents is available only in iOS 8+

Answer (score 1):

I use like this way:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"xml"]];
```

If your file included into the Resource folder of project navigator. otherwise you have to set your full path in `NSString` and use that in your `NSURL` path.